# What values should be passed in $this->_fileFactory->create()

Tags: magento2, invoice

I'm not able to download PDF on click of a button,but I'm able to generate the **xlsx** file.
How can I get the downloadable PDF on click of button in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are:

@param *string* **$fileName**

@param *string|array* **$content** - set to null to avoid starting output, $contentLength should be set explicitly in that case

@param *string* **$baseDir**

@param *string* **$contentType**

@param *int* **$contentLength** - explicit content length, if strlen($content) isn't applicable

[image]

You can use this file below of sample:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Invoice/AbstractInvoice/PrintAction.php
```

This **Method** is created here on the **line 52**:

```
vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/Http/FileFactory.php
```

Comment: If I need to  download the file which has explicit path , how should I specify  it in baseDir ? Thanks.